# Always showing highest voted questions

Tags: support

A few days ago I searched for highest voted questions in stackoverflow. Today when I logged in and clicked the questions link, it is showing the highest voted questions (of all time). I tried clearing the browser history, cache etc. Even I tried another browser. But the problem still remains. How can I restore the default behavior?

Comment: try click on [newest tab](http://stackoverflow.com/questions?sort=newest) and then check ... if they are showing after clearing the cookie and in different .. it mean they are storing in database

Comment: @NullPointer regarding your deleted answer here, Meta has no quality filter in place. You can post anything you want, there's only one exception that was added recently, where short answer with link to post on Meta in converted to a comment automatically.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your list will maintain the last ordering setting you selected. If you go to `featured`, then refresh the page, you will stay on `featured`.

As this is linked to your account, you will have to click `newest` first. When you do, your preferences will be set to `newest` by default.

Answer (score 4):

You are on the `votes` tab. Click the `newest` tab to show the newest questions.

[image: Choose the newest tab]